# Bash echo is removing quotations

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run a bash script where it's evaluating a piece of text with echo, but it's removing the quotations around "hi" and "bye":
file.txt

```
${VALUE}
"hi"  "bye"
```

script.sh

```
eval "echo \"$(<file.txt)\"" > file2.txt
# result: hi  bye, desired result: "hi" "bye"
```

I'm trying to use this method instead, but it doesn't seem like it's working for me:

```
echo -e \"eval \\\"cat <<EOF\n\\$$(cat file.txt)\nEOF\n\\\"\ > file2.txt
```

Comment: After the shell removes the quotes of the string passed to `eval`, the command to be evaluated is `echo "$(<file.txt)"`. This is also done by the shell (since _eval_ simply is a shell for the commands to be evaluated), and the quotes are removed (they just prevent word splitting and therefore make sure that sequences of spaces in file.txt are left intact), and you don't see any quotes. Of course, doing an `eval` here does not really make sense. Just remove it.

Comment: Do you just need a `cp file.txt file2.txt`? But if you need the content of file.txt be interpreted according to the rules of `echo` (for handling escape characters), `echo "$(<file.txt)" >file2.txt` should do. You give an example which shows a variable substitution (`VALUE`) , but you don't mention substitutions of i.e. `\n` or `\e'  in file.txt. Should they be expanded according to the _echo_ rules as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$ VALUE=123 eval "cat <<!
$(cat file.txt)
!
"
123
"hi"  "bye"
```

We choose the here-doc mechanism, because that's the interpolation mechanism available in the shell in which we can refer to variables like `${VALUE}`, and yet use unescaped double quotes, as if we were in a `'...'` double quote. Essentially, `file.txt` looks like a fragment (interior part) of a here-doc already.

We want this code to be executed:

```
cat <<!
${VALUE}
"hi"  "bye"
!
```

Except the two lines in the middle must come from the file—and they look like the file. So, we quote the whole thing in double quotes, and interpolate the file:

```
"cat <<!
$(cat file.txt)
!
"
```

That quote will produce the shell syntax we want; we just have to `eval` that syntax, and set up a value for `VALUE`.

Comment: Thanks the quotes show up! Just a follow up, the first line of the result is indented and I'm getting a warning (warning: here-document at line 32 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `!')) and it's printing a "!" at the end of the result. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem might be, but the ending delimiter of the here doc cannot have leading whitespace. I wrote a Bash-specific answer to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-code-blocks-indentation) in the Unix Stackexchange a couple of years ago, which is about how to write here documents with indentation (which doesn't appear in their output).